# Laravel 5.2 no auth::check() when exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I'm on a exception page (for example: `abort(404);`) I can't access the user data.

Normal page (`index.blade.php`)

[image: normal page (laravel 5.2)]

Exception or abort page

[image: abort or exception page (laravel 5.2)]

I want the `User` model also on the exception pages, but how do I do it?

For example:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
@else
    Not logged in
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `Kernel.php` in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

Move this Classes from `$middlewareGroups` to `$middleware`

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

So you'll have something like

```
  protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    ];
```